# What is the recommended way to load a dev version of a library locally and production version on production on Drupal 8

Tags: theming

For example with Vue.js on dev (local development) I would like to load the dev version like this:

```
vue:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    /libraries/vue/dist/vue.js: {}
  dependencies:
   - core/jquery
```

But on production, I would like to have it load like this (minified production version):

```
vue:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    /libraries/vue/dist/vue.min.js: {}
  dependencies:
   - core/jquery
```

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: There's probably many different ways to tackle this problem. Can you define what "best" means here to make it more concrete?

Comment: @ShawnConn I updated the question to "recommended" or would you say that is still not concrete?

Comment: I guess I should have phrased that comment differently, "less opinionated" is a better phrase (to make it a more definitive question that is more driven toward a consensus).

Anyway, since you're looking for 2 cents here, you could try adding a subtheme (enabled/disabled via config management based on env) that modifies the base theme with non-minified scripts.